# How to store id and display name with $scope in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, filter, angularjs-scope

> I am new to angularjs and not getting this silly thing.please help me
>   with the small problem.
>
> Below is my controller from where i get data to display in dropdowns
>   with filter.

```
 $http.get("http://www.adhr.adnacgroup.com/ADHRM/finalCandidatesJson.php")
  .then(function(response) 
  {$scope.names5 = $scope.names5 = response.data.service;});
  $scope.getInfo = function() 
  {
    if ($scope.empInfo1) 
    {
      $scope.company = [$scope.empInfo1["candidate_com","company_id"]];
      $scope.location = [$scope.empInfo1['candidate_loc']];
      $scope.department = [$scope.empInfo1['candidate_dep']];
      $scope.designation = [$scope.empInfo1['candidate_des']];
    }
  };
```

> and this is my html code to display.

```
<div class="control-group">                         
    <label class="control-label">Employee Name:</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <select ng-model="empInfo1" id="employee" class="span2" ng-options="emp.candidate_name for emp in names5 track by emp.candidate_id" ng-change="getInfo()">
    <option value="">-- Select Employee --</option>
    </select>                                           
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="control-group">                         
    <label class="control-label">Company Name:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select ng-model="empInfo2" id=company ng-disabled="!empInfo1" class="span2" ng-options="cancom for cancom in company">
        <option value="">-- Select Company --</option>
        </select>                                                                   
    </div>  
</div>
```

> To display i want candidate_com and to store in db i want company_id 
>   from below code but this code gives me only company_id to display.

```
$scope.company = [$scope.empInfo1["candidate_com","company_id"]];
```

> How to set ng-options to display candidate_com from this and to store
>   company_id in below ng-options:

```
<div class="controls">
    <select ng-model="empInfo2" id=company ng-disabled="!empInfo1" class="span2" ng-options="cancom for cancom in company">
    <option value="">-- Select Company --</option>
    </select>                                                                   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in select

```
 <select ng-model="empInfo1" id="employee" class="span2" ng-options="emp.company_id as emp.candidate_name for emp in names5 track by emp.candidate_id" ng-change="getInfo()">
<option value="">-- Select Employee --</option>
</select>
```